# Joining SQL tables to compare revenue vs expense

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Let me say first that I'm new to SQL, and learning much every day. With that said, here is my problem. I have a view that is already created (It shows revenue generated on equipment), but I need one more table added to it (Expenses against the equipment). When I try to add an inner join table, it create a bunch of duplicate views. Here is my original view (For the revenue portion of it):

```
SELECT
 <removed, there are about 25 of them>
FROM
 dbo.LRCON WITH (nolock) 
 INNER JOIN dbo.LRCONVIN WITH (nolock) ON dbo.LRCONVIN.ConId = dbo.LRCON.ConId 
 INNER JOIN dbo.LRBILCON WITH (nolock) ON dbo.LRBILCON.ConId = dbo.LRCONVIN.ConId AND dbo.LRBILCON.UntId = dbo.LRCONVIN.UntId 
 INNER JOIN dbo.LRBILITM WITH (nolock) ON dbo.LRBILITM.ParentItmId = dbo.LRBILCON.ItmId
 INNER JOIN dbo.LRBIL WITH (nolock) ON dbo.LRBIL.BilId = dbo.LRBILCON.BilId 
 INNER JOIN dbo.LRCONTYP WITH (nolock) ON dbo.LRCONTYP.ConTypId = dbo.LRCON.ConTypId 
 INNER JOIN dbo.COLOOKUP AS C1 WITH (nolock) ON C1.Id = dbo.LRBILITM.ItmTyp 
 INNER JOIN dbo.COLOOKUP AS C2 WITH (nolock) ON C2.Id = dbo.LRCONTYP.ConTyp 
 INNER JOIN dbo.VHVIN WITH (nolock) ON dbo.VHVIN.UntId = dbo.LRCONVIN.UntId
WHERE     
 (dbo.LRBIL.Status = 647) AND (dbo.LRBILITM.ItmTyp <> 274)
```

I then try to add another join:

```
INNER JOIN dbo.SVSLS WITH (nolock) on dbo.SVSLS.UntId = dbo.LRCONVIN.UntId
```

with the select statement:

```
ROUND(dbo.SVSLS.AmtSubtotal + dbo.SVSLS.AmtSupplies + dbo.SVSLS.AmtDiagnostic + dbo.SVSLS.AmtTax1 + dbo.SVSLS.AmtTax2, 2) AS SvcAmtSale
```

... but it produces many, many rows of duplicates because it adds the detail of each expense to each row of my original table.

Original table:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81145403/orginal_table.jpg

After I add my new join/select:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81145403/failed_table.jpg

How do I fix this? At the end of the day, I just want to compare my revenue vs expenses on equipment over a date range. I really don't care to have the individual detail of the expenses, just a grand total is fine with me.

Comment: Thinking about this more, the view mentioned above and the table I'm trying to join have nothing to do with each other except I want to compare them over a date range. It makes me think that I should even be attempting a join, but do something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the SvcSaleAmt the revenue that you are interested in?  And are the multiple detail rows separate entries on the same item?  If you do not necessarily care about the individual details, you can GROUP the items together.  In order to do this, you will need to get rid of the SlsId from your SELECT list, and add

`GROUP BY CusId, CusName, BillId, ConId, Prd, ConTypId, ....., AmtCos, AmtGpm`

Using all of the columns you have in your SELECT statement.  Replace the ROUND() AS SvcSaleAmt with:

`ROUND(SUM(dbo.SVSLS.AmtSubtotal + dbo.SVSLS.AmtSupplies + dbo.SVSLS.AmtDiagnostic + dbo.SVSLS.AmtTax1 + dbo.SVSLS.AmtTax2), 2) AS SvcSaleAmt`